# How i can deploy an maven spring project to tomcat 7 server in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, deployment, pom.xml

I use the apache tomcat 7 server, the server is installed on a OS - windows 8.
When i start the server by an tomcat monitor, then can satarted the tomcat manager `http://localhost:8080`
I use the eclipse IDE for java EE development.
In eclipse is installed maven and tomcat.

When i will the project deploy in the tomcat server by eclipse and i call in the browser this url `http://localhost:8080/deconFM_V5`, then comes an 404 HTTP status error 404.

My pom.xml is a follows.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>deconFM_V5</groupId>
    <artifactId>deconFM_V5</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>deconFM_V5 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <enconding>UTF-8</enconding>

        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jersey.version>1.13</jersey.version>
        <hb-core.version>3.3.2.GA</hb-core.version>
        <hb-annotation.version>3.4.0.GA</hb-annotation.version>
        <persist-api.version>1.0</persist-api.version>
        <javassist.version>3.12.1.GA</javassist.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>
        <hsqldb.version>2.2.6</hsqldb.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
        <commons-collections.version>3.2.1</commons-collections.version>
        <servlet-api.version>2.5</servlet-api.version>
        <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
        <jetty-plugin.version>6.1.26</jetty-plugin.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Jjunit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate und Persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hb-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${hb-annotation.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>${persist-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HSQLDB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey - Spring Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-plugin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then i can deploy a maven project to the tomcat server in the eclipse?

Greeting and thank much for your awnsers.

Comment: Does the server start cleanly i.e. are there any errors in the console? A 404 would lead me to believe it's either not deployed cleanly or is deployed under a different context root.

Answer (score 0):

To a simple deploy,undeploy of your java web application in a Tomcat, you can use tomcat-maven-plugin.

This is a simple configuration of the plugin
Add plugin declaration in pom.xml

```
    <!-- To launch embded tomcat server -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <url>http://yourTomcatUrl:yourTomcatPort/manager/text</url>
                <server>my-tomcat</server>
                <path>/myWebApp</path>
            </configuration>


        </plugin>
```

for use it you have to also modify your tomcat-users.xml in this way

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <user username="managerGui" password="pass" roles="manager-gui"/>

    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user username="manager" password="pass" roles="manager-script"/>
 </tomcat-users>
```

and add at your servers section of your settins.xml the following statement:

```
<server>
    <id>my-tomcat</id>
    <username>manager</username>
    <password>pass</password>
</server>
```

now to deploy the project, from the root folder of the project you can run mvn **tomcat7:deploy**

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your anwnser.

My pom.xml plugin code is edit and is follows:

```
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/</url>
                    <server>Development</server>
                    <path>/decon-fm-v5</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My settings.xml from maven:

```
<id>Development</id>
<username>manager</username>
<password>pass</password>
```

And this is my tomcat-users.xml

```
<user name="root" password="developer" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="managerGui" password="pass" roles="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="manager" password="pass" roles="manager-script"/>
```

After i the command mvn tomcat7:deploy in my windows console, returns an error.

This is the complete message.

```
E:\Development\Java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0>mvn tomc
at7:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-c
lean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom (4 KB at 7.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-p
lugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom (13 KB at 62.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/2
1/maven-parent-21.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/21
/maven-parent-21.pom (26 KB at 127.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/10/apache-10.
pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/10/apache-10.p
om (15 KB at 89.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-c
lean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar (25 KB at 115.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-i
nstall-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom (7 KB at 40.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
plugins/23/maven-plugins-23.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-p
lugins/23/maven-plugins-23.pom (9 KB at 61.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/2
2/maven-parent-22.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/22
/maven-parent-22.pom (30 KB at 149.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/11/apache-11.
pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/11/apache-11.p
om (15 KB at 91.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-i
nstall-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.jar (27 KB at 119.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-d
eploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom (6 KB at 36.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-s
ite-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom (21 KB at 107.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-s
ite-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.jar (122 KB at 305.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-a
ntrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom (5 KB at 30.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
plugins/12/maven-plugins-12.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-p
lugins/12/maven-plugins-12.pom (12 KB at 72.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-a
ntrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.jar (24 KB at 114.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-a
ssembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom (15 KB at 77.5 KB
/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
plugins/16/maven-plugins-16.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-p
lugins/16/maven-plugins-16.pom (13 KB at 75.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/1
5/maven-parent-15.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/15
/maven-parent-15.pom (24 KB at 117.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-a
ssembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.jar (204 KB at 390.0
KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-d
ependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom (12 KB at 68.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-d
ependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.jar (150 KB at 339.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-r
elease-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom (10 KB at 64.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/release/maven-
release/2.3.2/maven-release-2.3.2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/release/maven-r
elease/2.3.2/maven-release-2.3.2.pom (9 KB at 55.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-r
elease-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.jar (44 KB at 213.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadat
a.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata
.xml (22 KB at 131.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-m
etadata.xml (13 KB at 87.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.835s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jun 01 11:23:03 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat7' in the current project and in the p
lugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the re
positories [local (C:\Users\Daniel\.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.a
pache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundF
orPrefixException
E:\Development\Java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0>
```

Thank youre much for help.

Comment: Your problem is the place from where you run the command **mvn tomcat7:deploy**  Why are you here in **E:\Development\Java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0** directory? The command mvn tomcat7:deploy must be launched from the root of you project deconFM_V5, for example if you have the project in C:\Users\myUser\workspace, you have to go in C:\Users\myUser\workspace\deconFM_V5 and only here (the directory where there is a your pom.xml file) you can execute mvn tomcat7:deploy